# What are the pros and cons of using startManagingCursor()

Tags: java, android

At the moment I control my cursors as shown below. I would like to know what the benefit of using startManagingCursor() would be though. As at the moment I have a lot of cursors and every know and then get an error to do with them. Would this be beneficial if not better practice.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("GENERIC QUERY" , null);
c.moveToFirst();
numval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));                   
c.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all startManagingCursor is deperecated API 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor(android.database.Cursor)

Now we have to use  CursorLoader class with LoaderManager. To ans your question, if the activity is managing the cursor then it can optimize when the screen orientation happens n things like that. And activitity takes care of the cursor's lifecycle with its own lifecycle. Below is the snippet for android doc.

`This method allows the activity to take care of managing the given Cursor's lifecycle for you based on the activity's lifecycle. That is, when the activity is stopped it will automatically call deactivate() on the given Cursor, and when it is later restarted it will call requery() for you. When the activity is destroyed, all managed Cursors will be closed automatically`

Answer (score 0):

startManagingCursor ties your cursor lifecycle to your Activity lifecycle. This includes automatically requerying when your activity resumes. I tend to avoid using it because I don't necessarily want my queries to re-execute every time my activity is restarted.

As far as best practices goes, it might make more sense in cases where you expect your database to be updated when your activity is paused but even then I'm still partial to managing my own cursor. I also prefer to keep cursors open for short periods of time, so your sample matches the pattern I tend to use.